# onclick window.open not passing php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

When using the following, I click on the submit button and it opens "domain.com/bhl.php?search=" and not passing the $_GET variable like I need.

```
<form action="bhl.php" method="GET">
    <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
    <input type="submit" onclick="window.open('bhl.php?search=<?php echo $_GET['search'] ?>','targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=700, height=500'); return false;" />
</form>
```

Comment: remove `onclick()`, you can use `$_GET` in `bh1.php`.

Comment: Note that you are using quotation marks in a weird way. Just opening a bunch of them won't work as intended (since it will look like you are closing it).

Comment: @FirstOne There are no issue with quotation marks in that code.

Comment: @epascarello I might be mistaken, but I think I saw `onclick='window.open('b...`. Is it possible that a quick edition happened without showing the edit? Anyway, sorry about that, my bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you are reading the value of the search parameter when the page has originally loaded. PHP does not run after the page load. You would need to set the value with JavaScript when the button is clicked.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.open('bhl.php?search=' + encodeURIComponent(this.form.search.value),'targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=700, height=500'); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a PHP variable through since theres no value when the page loads.

Try sending the value with javascript:

```
<form action="bhl.php" method="GET">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
    <input type="submit" onclick="window.open('bhl.php?search='+document.getElementById('search').value,'targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=700, height=500'); return false;" />
</form>
```

Although I'd define a function then just call that function, rather than using inline javascript.